# calendar days total, asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been looking for a way to add the total days from two date ranges and find out how many days (Mondays 5, Tuesdays 4 etc....) and I have hit an issue.

I can get the days in a date range 1/1/2018 to 1/1/2019 = 365,
however, when that brakes down to days of the week I always get extra days.

```
Monday = 52
Tuesday = 53
Wednesday = 53
Thursday = 52
Friday = 52
Saturday = 52
Sunday = 52
```

And when put into a smaller date range the days don't match up with the days in the calendar month.

Where for April there are 5 Mondays I get 4 and so on.
I'm sure I am missing something small and sorry if I have.

```js
 public static void Main()
 {
   DateTime toDate = new DateTime(2019,01,01);
            DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(2018,01,01);

            TimeSpan objTimeSpan = toDate.Subtract(fromDate);
            Console.WriteLine(objTimeSpan.Days);


            List<DateTime> dates = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)((objTimeSpan).TotalDays) + 1).Select(n => toDate.AddDays(n)).ToList();

            var Mondays = dates.Count(x => x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday);
            Console.WriteLine(Mondays);

            var Tuesday = dates.Count(x => x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday);
            Console.WriteLine(Tuesday);

            var Wednesday = dates.Count(x => x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
            Console.WriteLine(Wednesday);

            var Thursday = dates.Count(x => x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday);
            Console.WriteLine(Thursday);

            var Friday = dates.Count(x => x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday);
            Console.WriteLine(Friday);

            var Saturday = dates.Count(x => x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday);
            Console.WriteLine(Saturday);

            var Sunday = dates.Count(x => x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
            Console.WriteLine(Sunday);
 }
```

```js
Best Result Calander is Set to Austraila (i can't put in images yet sorry)
----------------------------
startDate: 1/1/2018
endDate: 1/1/2019

Total Days: 365

Monday: 52
Tuesday: 52
Wednesday: 52
Thursday: 52
Friday: 52
Saturday: 52
Sunday: 52

---------------------------
startDate: 1/3/2018
endDate: 1/4/2019

Total Days: 31

Monday: 4
Tuesday: 4
Wednesday: 4
Thursday: 5
Friday: 5
Saturday: 5
Sunday: 4    
---------------------------
```

Any help would be awesome.
Set in C# and using ASP.NET to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you're adding `1` here: `((objTimeSpan).TotalDays) + 1`, because in your example you state that there are `365` days between 1/1/2018 and 1/1/2019 (which is correct, and is what you get when you do `toDate.Subtract(fromDate).Days`). But when you add 1 to this number, then your counts are going to be off. So you have to decide if you want the last date in the specified range to be inclusive or exclusive in your count. Exclusive is the default (1/1/2018 to 1/2/2018 would be considered one day). If you want it to be inclusive, then you have to also state that there are 366 days in the range.

The other problem you are running into is that, when generating your `IEnumerable<DateTime> dates`, you are adding the range values to the `toDate` instead of the `fromDate`. So, for example, if you were measuring the days of `April`, you would actually be getting 30 days from May.

Here's some sample code that may help explain better. First, a helper method to get the number of occurrences of a specific day in a date range:

```
private static int GetDayCount(IEnumerable<DateTime>dates, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    return dates == null ? 0 : dates.Count(date => date.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek);
}
```

Then we can create another method that uses this method for displaying the day information for a date range:

```
private static void DisplayDayInfo(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    var numDays = toDate.Subtract(fromDate).Days;

    Console.WriteLine("Total number of days from {0} to {1}: {2}\n",
        fromDate.ToShortDateString(), toDate.ToShortDateString(), numDays);

    var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, numDays).Select(days => fromDate.AddDays(days));

    foreach (DayOfWeek dayOfWeek in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{dayOfWeek}s: \t{GetDayCount(dates, dayOfWeek)}");
    }
}
```

And with those out of the way, we can display the day info for the year 2018 and for the month of April, 2018:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // Show info for 2018
    DisplayDayInfo(new DateTime(2018, 01, 01), new DateTime(2019, 01, 01));

    // Draw a separation line
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', Console.WindowWidth));

    // Show info for April 2018
    DisplayDayInfo(new DateTime(2018, 04, 01), new DateTime(2018, 05, 01));

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Mate Thank you. I had to so a bit of tweaking but nothing over the top. you are awesome and I feel a bit silly for the +1. that "GetDateCount" and having it and an array saved my butt.

Answer (score 0):

- Your loop should be from 0 to TotalDays-1 (not +1)
- Also, you should be adding days to FromDate (not ToDate)
- if I were you, I'd break that method into smaller ones and write some unit tests